# split a fasta file and rename on the basis of first line

Tags: python, linux, split, fasta

I have a huge file with following content:

filename: input.txt

```
>chr1
jdlfnhl
dh,ndh
dnh.

dhjl

>chr2
dhfl
dhl
dh;l

>chr3

shgl
sgl

>chr2_random
dgld
```

I need to split this file in such a way that I get four separate file as below:

file 1: chr1.fa

```
>chr1
jdlfnhl
dh,ndh
dnh.

dhjl
```

file 2: chr2.fa

```
>chr2
dhfl
dhl
dh;l
```

file 3: chr3.fa

```
>chr3

shgl
sgl
```

file 4: chr2_random.fa

```
>chr2_random
dgld
```

I tried csplit in linux, but could not rename them by the text immediately after  ">".

```
csplit -z input.txt '/>/' '{*}'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you indicate you're on a Linux box 'awk' seems to be the right tool for the job.

**USAGE:**
`./foo.awk your_input_file`

**foo.awk:**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^>chr/ {
    OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa"
}

OUT {
    print >OUT
}
```

You can do that also in one line:

```
awk '/^>chr/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa"}; OUT {print >OUT}' your_input
```

Comment: I forgot that - fixed it now.

Comment: There' another point: this solution retains the blank lines at the end of subfiles. Is that an issue?

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Please, do you know how to modify it in order to skip those files that would contain string "random" in their names?

Comment: use this: `!(OUT ~/random/)  {print >OUT}`

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself wanting to do anything more complicated with FASTA/FASTQ files, you should consider Biopython.

Here's a post about modifying and re-writing FASTQ files: http://news.open-bio.org/news/2009/09/biopython-fast-fastq/

And another about splitting up FASTA files: http://lists.open-bio.org/pipermail/biopython/2012-July/008102.html

Answer (score 1):

Slightly messy script, but should work on a large file as it only reads one line at a time

To run, you do `python thescript.py input.txt` (or it'll read from stdin, like `cat input.txt | python thescript.py`)

```
import sys
import fileinput

in_file = False

for line in fileinput.input():
    if line.startswith(">"):
        # Close current file
        if in_file:
            f.close()

        # Make new filename
        fname = line.rstrip().partition(">")[2]
        fname = "%s.fa" % fname

        # Open new file
        f = open(fname, "w")
        in_file = True

        # Write current line
        f.write(line)

    elif in_file:
        # Write line to currently open file
        f.write(line)

    else:
        # Something went wrong, no ">chr1" found yet
        print >>sys.stderr, "Line %r encountered, but no preceeding > line found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use the fastaexplode program from the [exonerate suite](http://www.animalgenome.org/bioinfo/resources/manuals/exonerate/):

```
$ fastaexplode -h
fastaexplode from exonerate version 2.2.0
Using glib version 2.30.2
Built on Jan 12 2012
Branch: unnamed branch

fastaexplode: Split a fasta file up into individual sequences
Guy St.C. Slater. guy@ebi.ac.uk. 2000-2003.

Synopsis:
--------
fastaexplode <path>

General Options:
---------------
-h --shorthelp [FALSE] <TRUE>
   --help [FALSE] 
-v --version [FALSE] 

Sequence Input Options:
----------------------
-f --fasta [mandatory]  <*** not set ***>
-d --directory [.] 

--
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines=f.read()
    lines=lines.split('>')
    lines=['>'+x for x in lines[1:]]
    for x in lines:
        file_name=x.split('\n')[0][1:]  #use this variable to create the new file
        fil=open(file_name+'.fa','w')
        fil.write(x)
        fil.close()
```

Comment: The question mentions a "huge" file, potentially loading the entire thing at once might use too much memory... or maybe not, so +1

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to try this with python ,You can use this code

```
f2 = open("/dev/null", "r")
f = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    if ">" in line:
        f2.close()
        f2 = open(line.split(">")[1]),"w")
    else:
        f2.write(line)

f.close()
```

Comment: The indentation is missing, as is the `:` on `else`

Comment: Ya I tried editing but its getting request timeout,Dont know whats wrong with opera :(

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, BioPython could have been used. Installing it in a virtualenv is easy:

```
virtualenv biopython_env
source biopython_env/bin/activate
pip install numpy
pip install biopython
```

And once this is done, splitting the fasta file is easy. Let's assume you have the path to the fasta file in the `fasta_file` variable:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

parser = SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta")
for entry in parser:
   SeqIO.write(entry, "chr{}.fa".format(entry.id), "fasta")
```

Note that this version of format works in Python2.7, but it might not work in older versions.

As for performance, I used this to split the human genome reference from the 1000 Genomes project in negligible time, but I don't know how it would work for larger files.

Comment: `str.format()` was introduced in 2.6 [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;


my %hash =();
my $key = '';
open F, "input.txt", or die $!;
while(<F>){
    chomp;
    if($_ =~ /^(>.+)/){
        $key = $1;
    }else{
       push @{$hash{$key}}, $_ ;
    }   
}

foreach(keys %hash){
    my $key1 = $_;
    my $key2 ='';
    if($key1 =~ /^>(.+)/){
        $key2 = $1;
    }
    open MYOUTPUT, ">","$key2.fa", or die $!;
    print MYOUTPUT join("\n",$_,@{$hash{$_}}),"\n";
    close MYOUTPUT;
}
```