# Renaming files based on number in first line

Tags: awk, gawk

I used the awk answer from Theodros Zelleke, from [split a fasta file and rename on the basis of first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818495/split-a-fasta-file-and-rename-on-the-basis-of-first-line?rq=1), as a template for the code below:

```
awk '/[[:digit:]]/ {OUT=substr($0,1) ".txt"}; OUT {print > OUT}' /path/to/file
```

The above code resulted in the file name consisting of the whole 1st line and the file only included the first 2 lines rather than the complete original file.

I have hundreds of files that I want to rename based on the Location Number which is on the first line of each text file. Below are 2 examples of the text files that I am processing.

file 1 will become "1000030.txt"

```
Location Number.: 1000030 Location Name, State

Text: Text

More Text  
More Text  
More Text
```

file 2 will become "100003099111134.txt"

```
Location Number.: 100003099111134 Location Name, State

Text: Text

More Text  
More Text
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `substr` here does not do nothing, just return the whole line, so `{OUT=substr($0,1) ".txt"}` is equal to `{OUT=$0 ".txt"}`

Answer (score 4):

To copy old files to new files with whats in the first line, you can use this `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==1 {file=$3} {print > (file".txt")}' oldfiles*
```

It reads the first line and set it as the new filename.

Comment: Given the data, it looks like you should be capturing `$3` as the basis of the file name, rather than `$0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are off course correct. I just wake up :)

Comment: Some `awk`s cannot handle that redirect, since they consider it ambiguous. You could use `print > (file".txt")` instead or use a variable..

Comment: @Scrutinizer Updated post to make it more portable.

Comment: @Jotne Thank you for your suggestion, it worked with a minor edit to the existing code .txt")}'.

Comment: @iembry fixed typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally; I'd just write a simple shell script.  Something like:

```
# Untested example...
for f in *; do
  n=`head -1 $f|cut -c19-26`
  mv $f $n
done
```

Comment: 19-26 won't capture the number correctly in the example with location number 100003099111134.   You might be OK with `cut -d' ' -f3` though.  You should fix the spacing in the assignment though (you probably don't have a command called `n`!) and it is better to use `$(head -1 "$f" | cut -d' ' -f 3)` rather than back quotes.